# Help with ConnectionStrings for the ApplicationService

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, database-connection, connection-string

Ok I have an application running with 2 data base, my database that is used for storing the information needed, and the applicationservice database that is used for storing the accounts and security information (I'm using the asp.net Memembership Provider). But the thing is that for some reason I cant create a conecction so my application service database be created at my localhost Sql Server.

```
  <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;initial catalog=AppServiceDB;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="SummumnetDB" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;initial catalog=SummumnetDB;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

SummumnetDB, is created without problems in my local SqlServer but AppServices don't. Maybe I need to add something else to the AppService conecctionString. Thanxs for your help

Comment: How is SummumnetDB created? Are you using EF Code-First?

Comment: Yes I'am, SummumnetDB its the name of the DbContext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `SummumnetDB`, your `AppServiceDB` isn't automatically created for you. You need to create your membership database manually.

The easiest way is to run `aspnet_regsql.exe` from *Visual Studio Command Prompt* and follow the wizard. You can find more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx).